# How can I create an ImageMagick montage without empty space?

Tags: imagemagick, montage

I am creating a large number of montages using a set of images.

The way I want the montages arranged is with three images across the top and two images across the bottom. The command I have right now is as follows:

```
montage logo.png 1430410987_ACR02.png 1430410987_ACR01.png \
        1430410987_LHC1.png 1430410987_LHC_dashboard.png   \
       -mode Concatenate -tile 3x3 1_tile.png
```

This results in a montage of the appropriate arrangement, but features a large empty region to the right, something I don't want. I note that the width of the empty region is the width of the largest of the images used in the montage.

[image]

What should I do to ensure that this large empty region is not created?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your right in identifying the empty region having the same width of the largest image. This is caused by `-tile 3x3` which assumes 3 images per row. At the bottom of [Montage Usage](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/) there's a section dedicated to gaps in a montage image, and how it can be controlled with `null:`. Try the following...

```
montage logo.png \
        1430410987_ACR02.png \
        1430410987_ACR01.png \
        1430410987_LHC1.png \
        1430410987_LHC_dashboard.png \
        null: \
        -mode Concatenate \
        -tile 3x3 \
        1_tile.png
```

**Another alternative**

You can also use `convert`, sub-process & `-append` to rebuild the tile image one row at a time.

```
convert \( logo.png 1430410987_ACR02.png 1430410987_ACR01.png +append \) \
        \( 1430410987_LHC1.png 1430410987_LHC_dashboard.png +append \) \
        -append 1_tile.png
```

Comment: Nice work - way to go! No idea why, but I find the second option far more intuitive. Actually, I think I do know why... because the image names are laid out exactly the same way as the images themselves - I must be a visual thinker! Anyway, nice solution :-)

Comment: Thanks @MarkSetchell! I agree with you on the second option. Perhaps because it offers more control / flexibility.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for your knowledgeable solution for ```montage``` and your clear solution for ```convert```. Both are great.